# Arranging rows in custom order using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

With `arrange` function in `dplyr`, we can arrange row in ascending or descending order. Wonder how to arrange rows in custom order. Please see MWE.

```
Reg <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 2)
Res <- rep(c("Urban", "Rural"), times = 3)
set.seed(12345)
Pop <- rpois(n = 6, lambda = 500000)
df <- data.frame(Reg, Res, Pop)

df
   Reg   Res    Pop
1    A Urban 500414
2    A Rural 500501
3    B Urban 499922
4    B Rural 500016
5    C Urban 501638
6    C Rural 499274

df %>%
  arrange()
```

**Desired Output**

```
   Reg   Res    Pop
5    C Urban 501638
6    C Rural 499274
1    A Urban 500414
2    A Rural 500501
3    B Urban 499922
4    B Rural 500016
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

We can use `factor` to change the `order` in a custom way

```
df %>%
    arrange(factor(Reg, levels = LETTERS[c(3, 1, 2)]), desc(Res), desc(Pop))
#  Reg   Res    Pop
#1   C Urban 501638
#2   C Rural 499274
#3   A Urban 500414
#4   A Rural 500501
#5   B Urban 499922
#6   B Rural 500016
```

Or with `match` to get the index and `arrange` on it

```
df %>%
    arrange(match(Reg, c("C", "A", "B")), desc(Res), desc(Pop))
```

---

If we have multiple columns to `arrange` in descending order

```
df %>%
     arrange_at(2:3, desc) %>%
     arrange(match(Reg, c("C", "A", "B")))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for nice solution. Is there any was to use `desc` for all remaining variables without typing their names? Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208  Thanks for the note.  I added another option.  Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, to echo @MYaseen208, is there any way to pick a couple to be at the bottom, but have the rest at the top?  For instance, if i have 20 vars, and i want 2 of them at the bottom, this method seems to only work if I name the first 18 in the match.  Regardless of the desc() and !match I use, I always get the unnamed values at the bottom.

Comment: Just a side note for future viewers: first solution can be shortened to `df %>% arrange(factor(Reg, levels = LETTERS[c(3,1,2)]))`

Comment: It seems that if the sorting variable is already defined as an ordered factor outside of `arrange`, the behaviour of `arrange` is still to order alphabetically... How come?

Comment: @FonsMA  Not clear about the comment.  Can you post a small example

Answer (score 14):

I used the **slice()** function:

```
   df %<>%
   slice(5,6,1:4)
```

Comment: I found this the simplest and easiest to follow answer but found I could use %>% rather than %<>%

Answer (score 5):

using ***data.table***

```
df1[order(factor(Reg,levels = LETTERS[c(3,1,2)]))]
```

Here df1 is data.table