# tbl_merge: sort variables alphabetically in merged tbl_regression models {gtsummary}

Tags: r, gtsummary

Consider the example below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

    t1 <- trial %>%
      na.exclude() %>%
      lm(marker ~ age + ttdeath, .) %>%
      tbl_regression()
    t2 <- trial %>%
      na.exclude() %>%
      lm(marker ~ age + response + death, .) %>%
      tbl_regression()
    t3 <- trial %>%
      na.exclude() %>%
      lm(marker ~ age + stage + death, .) %>%
      tbl_regression()
    t4 <- trial %>%
      na.exclude() %>%
      lm(marker ~ stage + grade + death, .) %>%
      tbl_regression()
    
    tbl_merge(list(t1, t2, t3 ,t4))
```

[image]

In the characteristic tab, variables are only alphabetically within a particular model.
For example, when looking only at Table 1 is fine, it's A-M-T.

However, when looking at mutiple tables at once, the order is not alphabetical.
Is there a way to sort variables alphabetically within all the tables?

> E.g. Age, Grade, Months to Death/Censor, Patient Died...

I assume the way to do this is by `gtsummary::modify_table_body` into `dplyr::arrange`,
but I don't know how to do it exactly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: actually, anyway to manually modify the order of variables would be helpful as well, ignore this if it's too difficult.

Edit2: I forgot to mention that there's glance statistics involved as well, such as `add_glance_table(adj.r.squared) %>% modify_table_body(~.x %>% arrange(row_type == "glance_statistic"))` (which is not in this example), so I imagine there is a possibility that the sorting of variables messes with the order of glance statistics as well. Excuse me for making this complicated, but it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that `modify_table_body()` is the way to go. You'll first want to arrange the order to put the glance table at the bottom, then you arrange by `"var_label"` to put the variables in alphabetical order. `"var_label"` is a column in `.$table_body`. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

t1 <- trial %>%
  lm(marker ~ age + ttdeath, .) %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_glance_table(adj.r.squared)
t2 <- trial %>%
  lm(marker ~ age + response + death, .) %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_glance_table(adj.r.squared)
t3 <- trial %>%
  lm(marker ~ age + stage + death, .) %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_glance_table(adj.r.squared)
t4 <- trial %>%
  lm(marker ~ stage + grade + death, .) %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_glance_table(adj.r.squared)

tbl <- 
  tbl_merge(list(t1, t2, t3 ,t4)) %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>% 
      dplyr::arrange(
        row_type == "glance_statistic", # sort glance table to bottom
        var_label                       # sort by the variable label (a hidden column) 
      )
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-12-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It is obvious that the solution by @Daniel D. Sjoberg is best.
But here is an alternative strategy that is I think more flexible.

Daniel D. Sjoberg provided the hint using `tbl_stack()` [Supress table header in tbl_regression of gt_summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70411865/supress-table-header-in-tbl-regression-of-gt-summary?noredirect=1#comment124471075_70411865)

Here is how it works:

1. First use `tbl_merge` as you did
2. Then use `tbl_split` in each variable row of the table. You will get a list.
3. Assign names to the list elements
4. then use `tbl_stack` in the order you wish!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

x <- tbl_merge(list(t1, t2, t3 ,t4))

y <- x %>% 
  tbl_split(variables = c(age, ttdeath, response, death, stage, grade)) 

age <- y[[1]]
ttdeath <- y[[2]]
response <- y[[3]]
death <- y[[4]]
stage <- y[[5]]
grade <- y[[6]]

tbl_stack(list(age, grade, ttdeath, death, response, stage))
```

[image]

Comment: I've found a possibly better way to do this (in conjunction with Daniel), which is taken from [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129322/arranging-rows-in-custom-order-using-dplyr/46129338.

You can 
`modify_table_body(
      ~.x %>% 
        dplyr::arrange(
          match(var_label, c("variable_name_1", "variable_name_2", [...]))
        )`

to custom modify your variable orders by hand!

Comment: That was my first solution ever. But the thing is that you can not get a gt_summary table from a tibble or dataframe.