# Arrange rows in custom order in R using a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, dplyr

This is similar to this: [Arranging rows in custom order using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129322/arranging-rows-in-custom-order-using-dplyr)
But I am looking for different results...

```
v1 <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 2)
v2 <- rep(c("Seg1", "Seg2"), times = 3)
v3<- c(300,200,500,700,600,550)
df<- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
```

so that's my original df and we see the order A,A,B,B,C,C
I want to change the order so it will be C,A,B,C,A,B
I tried using

```
df %>%
    arrange(match(v1, c("C", "A", "B")), desc(v2), desc(v3))
```

but this gives us a result that looks like C,C,A,A,B,B

original df:

[image: original df]

results I want:

[image: result I want]

unwanted result I get:

[image: unwanted result]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear but I think you want `v2` as the primary key? `df[order(df$v2, match(df$v1, c("C", "A", "B"))),]`

Answer (score 1):

```r
v1 <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 2)
v2 <- rep(c("Seg1", "Seg2"), times = 3)
v3<- c(300,200,500,700,600,550)
df<- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  arrange(v2, factor(v1, levels = c("C", "A", "B"))) 
#>   v1   v2  v3
#> 1  C Seg1 600
#> 2  A Seg1 300
#> 3  B Seg1 500
#> 4  C Seg2 550
#> 5  A Seg2 200
#> 6  B Seg2 700
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>