# Keep order of values when filtering a dataframe using %in%

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

How can I filter data using dplyr, so that the resulting df displays the data not in the original order, but in the order of the filtering query vector? See the example here below:

```
df <- tibble(name = letters,
         score = 1:26)

df %>% filter(name %in% c("g","m","b"))
```

I get "b,g,m", filtering where I would like to get "g,m,b". Is it possible within filter()?

Comment: Community recommended answer on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46129338/16730940

Comment: You can find answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11977102/1315767

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not likely possible with `filter` as the condition is just applying the same check to each row and keeping those that pass test. A roundabout way, but perhaps solvable with a join:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(name = letters,
             score = 1:26)

df %>% 
  left_join(tibble(name = c("g", "m", "b")), .)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(name)`
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   name  score
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 g         7
#> 2 m        13
#> 3 b         2
```

Answer (score 4):

Loop through the values and subset:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c("g","m","b"), function(i) df[ df$name == i, ]))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   name  score
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 g         7
# 2 m        13
# 3 b         2
```

Answer (score 3):

not with just `filter()`, but you can use the same vector and supply it to `factor()` as a level argument, then use that to `arrage()` the data.

```
df %>% filter(name %in% c("g","m","b")) %>% arrange(factor(name, levels = c("g","m","b")))
```

does the trick

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name  score
  <chr> <int>
1 g         7
2 m        13
3 b         2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `slice`

```
v <- c("g", "m", "b")
df %>%
  slice(first(order(match(name, v)), length(v)))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name  score
  <chr> <int>
1 g         7
2 m        13
3 b         2
```